# Cannot get '/endpoint'

Tags: node.js, express

guys!

I can not understand why I can't reach the service. For example, I do not see anything in the logs in the terminal on the 11th line of the service, and, accordingly, I cannot reach '/something'.

But the logs in routes in the controller works.

So, what am I missing? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

test.controller.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { IRouter } from 'express';
import TestService from '../services/test.service';

class TestController {
  private testService: TestService;

  constructor(private router: IRouter) {
    this.router = router;
    this.testService = new TestService();
    this.routes();
  }

  public routes() {
    this.router.route('/something').get(this.testService.testRequest);
  }
}

export default TestController;
```

test.service.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

class TestService {
  constructor() {
    this.testRequest = this.testRequest.bind(this);
  }

  public async testRequest(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      console.log('test');
      res.send('Hello');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

export default TestService;
```

app.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import express, { Application, Router } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import headersMiddleware from '../helpers/headers';
import ExampleController from '../controllers/example.controller';
import AuthController from '../controllers/auth.controller';
import LoginController from '../controllers/login.controller';
import TestController from '../controllers/test.controller';
import TestService from '../services/test.service';

class App {
  public app: Application;

  public router: Router;

  public exampleController: ExampleController;

  public authController: AuthController;

  public loginController: LoginController;

  public testController: TestController;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.set_config();
    this.exampleController = new ExampleController(this.router);
    this.authController = new AuthController(this.router);
    this.loginController = new LoginController(this.router);
    this.testController = new TestController(this.router);
  }

  private set_config() {
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(headersMiddleware);
    this.app.use(express.static('static'));
    this.app.use('/api/v1', this.router);
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

Comment: You would need to make a request to `/api/v1/something` since you mounted your router at the `/api/v1` prefix

Comment: FYI add `cors()` **before** any other middleware otherwise any errors handling requests will break CORS integration

Answer (score -1):

I forgot added '/api/v1' into my request before '/something'.